# java applet for kilometer to meter

Tags: java

am just trying to create an applet function in java

am trying to create an program to convert kilometer to miles

but am stuck, i can enter the input but i can't see the output

am just mentioning where i think the problem might be :)

just have an look

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Converter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Distance : ");
    JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
    JButton button = new JButton("Convert");
    JTextArea output = new JTextArea(10,15);
    CheckboxGroup cbg = new CheckboxGroup();
    Checkbox cb1 = new Checkbox("Convert MILES to KM", cbg, true);
    Checkbox cb2 = new Checkbox("Convert KM to MILES", cbg, false);
    

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Converter s = new Converter();
        s.setVisible(true);
        
    }

    public Converter(){
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(300,400);  
        //left-down-width-hegiht
        cb1.setBounds(60,30,150,30);
        cb2.setBounds(60,60,150,30);
        label.setBounds(30,90,120,30);
        input.setBounds(90,95,170,20);
        button.setBounds(100,130,90,30);
        output.setBounds(45,168,200,165);
                
        add(cb1);
        add(cb2);
        add(label);
        add(input);
        add(button);
        add(output);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        
        if (cb1.getState() ) {
            if (e.getSource() == button ){
                double d = Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
                double d2 =  d* 0.62;
                String str2 = String.valueOf(d2); 

                output.setText(str2);
            }
            else { 
            }
        }
        button.addActionListener(this); //I think this lone has little problem
    }        
}
'''
```

Comment: Applets are entirely dead. You can run a Swing (JFrame) application like a regular program, though.

Comment: Your program is already a standalone Swing application, and has nothing to do with applets. The line `button.addActionListener(this);` needs to be inside the constructor, and not inside the `actionPerformed` method where it is now.

Comment: You are adding the listener to the button inside the `actionPerformed` method (of the listener), that means the action must have been performed once before the listener could  even listen to actions performed. Put `button.addActionListener(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: (1-) 1) This has nothing to do with an applet. This appears to be a Swing application 2) Don't use a CheckBox. That is an AWT component. For Swing you should use `JCheckBox`. 3) Don't a null layout with setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with `layout managers`. 4) Don't extend JFrame. You only extend a class when you add functionality to the class. Adding components to the class is not adding functionality. 5) Learn Swing basics by reading the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections that go into more detail with examples.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you add the actionListener only after you click the button, which means it will never get added in the first place.

Move the line

```
    button.addActionListener(this); //I think this lone has little problem
```

to the constructor instead.